# MySQL select and update in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to do a select and join a table, then update that table?

I'm basically looking to increase the price by 5% on all products owned by a particular supplier.  The problem is the pricing details are held in a separate table to the products themselves.

I know this syntax is not correct, but it will give you the gist of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
update 
    products_quantity_pricing set price = price + (price/100*5)
where (select 
    products.supplier_id,
    products_quantity_pricing.price 
    from products 
join
    products_quantity_pricing on products_quantity_pricing.product_id = products.id 
where products.supplier_id = 7 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `JOIN` directly into the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE products_quantity_pricing AS pqp
JOIN products AS p ON pqp.product_id = p.id
SET price = price + (price/100*5)
WHERE p.supplier_id = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update  products_quantity_pricing set price = price + (price/100*5)
where  products_quantity_pricing.price  in 
(select  products_quantity_pricing.price 
    from products  join
    products_quantity_pricing on products_quantity_pricing.product_id = products.id 
where products.supplier_id = 7 )
```